# displaying django form error messages instead of just the field name

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form and I want to display the errors in a for loop.

```
{% for error in form.errors %}
    <tr><td>{{ error }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

By doing this the {{ error }} only contains the field name that has an error, but not the error message. How can I display the error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all field errors in a form like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {{ field.errors|striptags }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or for a specific field:

```
{% if form.subject.errors %}
    <ol>
    {% for error in form.subject.errors %}
        <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endif %}
```

More Infos here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template