# How to extract Django Form errors message without the HTML tags

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to extract the messages and field.

For Example, I have this django form error result

```
<ul class="errorlist">
   <li>__all__
     <ul class="errorlist nonfield">
        <li>Pointofsale with this Official receipt and Company already exists.</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

from the output of this code

```
def post_sale(request):
    sale_form = request["data"]

    if sale_form.is_valid():
       save_form.save()
    else:
       print save_form.errors
```

But what i need to achieve is to get the message without the tags, so i could just return those message in plain string/text.

```
def post_sale(request):
    sale_form = request["data"]

    if sale_form.is_valid():
       save_form.save()
    else:
       # This is just pseudo code
       for field in save_form.errors:
           field = str(field["field"})
           message = str(field["error_message"])

           print "Sale Error Detail"
           print field
           print message

           error_message = { 'field':field,'message':message }
           error_messages.append(error_message )
```

The output would be:

```
Sale Error Detail
(the field where form error exists)
Pointofsale with this Official receipt and Company already exists.
```

### Explored Questions and Documentations

- [displaying django form error messages instead of just the field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585606/displaying-django-form-error-messages-instead-of-just-the-field-name)
- [Getting a list of errors in a Django form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035288/getting-a-list-of-errors-in-a-django-form)
- [django form errors. get the error without any html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694489/django-form-errors-get-the-error-without-any-html-tags)
- [How do I display the Django '__all__' form errors in the template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525905/how-do-i-display-the-django-all-form-errors-in-the-template)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/

Thanks, please tell if something is amiss or something needs clarification so i could fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `errors` property of a bound form will contain all errors raised by that form, as a dictionary. The key is a field or other special values (such as `__all__`), and the value is a list of one or more errors.

Here is a simple example on how this works:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> class MyForm(forms.Form):
...     name = forms.CharField()
...     email = forms.EmailField()
...     
>>> f = MyForm() # Note, this is an unbound form
>>> f.is_valid()
False
>>> f.errors # No errors
{}
>>> f = MyForm({}) # Now, the form is bound (to an empty dictionary)
>>> f.is_valid()
False
>>> f.errors # dictionary of errors
{'name': [u'This field is required.'], 'email': [u'This field is required.']}
```

In your view, depending on what you want you can just return the value of `form.errors`, or parse it to whatever structure your need.

```
for field, errors in form.errors.items():
   print('Field: {} Errors: {}'.format(field, ','.join(errors))
```

For the specific error you have mentioned, it is a custom error raised as a result of overriding the `clean()` method - which is why it is listed under the special identifier `__all__` and not under a specific field.

This is mentioned in the [forms reference, under validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/):

> Note that any errors raised by your `Form.clean()` override will not be
>   associated with any field in particular. They go into a special
>   “field” (called `__all__`), which you can access via the
>   `non_field_errors()` method if you need to. If you want to attach errors
>   to a specific field in the form, you need to call `add_error()`.

Comment: Thanks! this is what i need